# How to setvalues() in the row of a column which is in the same row as a cell in another column with google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following script which works great, for a product code in column P of the BLOCK ORDERS sheet, ss1, it extracts the price from either the quotation worksheets ss2 if a sheet name matches the name of a particular customer, or if not then the price is taken from products sheet ss3. The price is input into column Z of the BLOCK ORDERS sheet. The problem I have is how to get the script to put the price in the same row as that of the product code?

```
function updateQuotationPrice() { 
  
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1VlLbwBtYyOQBRz-8JHRn_jVhaAC7Tl68OXSltoQwaBU"); //BLOCKS UPDATE 
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("10tb0zE_8i849T-hL6mU-Pw_4V-aMzNZJGNOFYG1F3qk"); //Quotation
  var ss3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pt7YnN9fmoD4PE0o9oVPezK8Qz6ZmabyJbWXfdzFeMU"); //PRODUCTS
 
 //Extract data from User Update
  var lr1 = ss1.getSheetByName("BLOCK ORDERS").getLastRow();
  var data1 = ss1.getSheetByName("BLOCK ORDERS").getRange(2, 6, lr1, 61).getValues();

  //Extract data from Quotation Spreadsheet
  var sheetNames2 = [];
  ss2.getSheets().forEach(x => sheetNames2.push(x.getName()));

  //Process data 1
  var output = [];
  data1.forEach((x,i) => {
    var zoneSurcharge = x[58];
    
    if (sheetNames2.includes(x[0]) && ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10])).length > 0 ) { 
      if (x[9] == "EURO" && x[10] != "") {
        output.push([ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][3]+zoneSurcharge]);
      }
      else if (x[9] == "STERLING" && x[10] != "") {
        output.push([ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][2]+zoneSurcharge]);
      }
    }
    else  
      if (x[9] == "EURO"  && x[10] != "" ) {surcharges = zoneSurcharge 
        output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][3]+zoneSurcharge]) ;
      }
      else 
      if (x[9] == "STERLING"  && x[10] != "") {surcharges = zoneSurcharge 
        output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][2]+zoneSurcharge]); 
      }   
  });
  console.log(output);
 //Output 
 ss1.getSheetByName("BLOCK ORDERS").getRange(2, 26, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output); 
   }
```

The output range `ss1.getSheetByName("BLOCK ORDERS").getRange(2, 26, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);` starts at row 2. I require the output to correspond with the same row which contains the product code. Sometimes the product code could be in row 2 or row 3 ,or row 4 etc.
The BLOCK ORDERS sheets can be viewed at
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VlLbwBtYyOQBRz-8JHRn_jVhaAC7Tl68OXSltoQwaBU/edit?usp=sharing
The QUOTATIONS sheets can be viewed at
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10tb0zE_8i849T-hL6mU-Pw_4V-aMzNZJGNOFYG1F3qk/edit?usp=sharing
The PRODUCTS sheets can be viewed at
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pt7YnN9fmoD4PE0o9oVPezK8Qz6ZmabyJbWXfdzFeMU/edit?usp=sharing
Thank you for any help with this

[image: Input situation]

[image: Current Output situation]

[image: Correct Output situation]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike, I edited the post to include the input situation, the current output situation and the required output situation. I hope you can follow. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your added 3 images, which are the sample input and output situations?

Comment: @Tanaike, the first picture is the sample input, the second picture is the sample output in column Z by the current script. The third picture is the output in column Z which I require. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. About the 1st, 2nd images and the 3rd image, those are the same sheet?

Comment: @Tanaike, yes these are all from the same sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. Although unfortunately, now, I cannot still understand your question, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251987/discussion-between-les-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there are any edge cases that you need to take into account, but the way your current script works, the `output` prices will always be in the same order as your `products` in column P. So all you need to do is to fill the `output` array with blank strings when you also find a blank product. So your loop would look like this:

```js
  var output = [];
  data1.forEach((x, i) => {
    var zoneSurcharge = x[58];
    if (x[10] == "") {
      output.push([""])
    } else {
      if (sheetNames2.includes(x[0]) && ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10])).length > 0) {
        if (x[9] == "EURO" && x[10] != "") {
          output.push([ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][3] + zoneSurcharge]);
        }
        else if (x[9] == "STERLING" && x[10] != "") {
          output.push([ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][2] + zoneSurcharge]);
        }
      }
      else
        if (x[9] == "EURO" && x[10] != "") {
          surcharges = zoneSurcharge
          output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][3] + zoneSurcharge]);
        }
        else
          if (x[9] == "STERLING" && x[10] != "") {
            surcharges = zoneSurcharge
            output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][2] + zoneSurcharge]);
          }
    }
  });
```

As you can see, I just encased everything in another `if`. So for a product input like `["B94", "", "B94", "C3520"]` your `output` will look like `[[ '77' ],[ '' ],[ 71 ],[ '103' ]]`. The products will match with their prices. You can also add to the condition any other columns that you expect could be blank like `currency`, or to validate for missing product codes, but this will depend on how your sheet works. The general idea is that you just want to fill the `output` with blank rows whenever you cannot retrieve a price so it will match the input.

The hard way would probably be something like keeping track of the `index` rows in the `forEach` to create a [`RangeList`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) with only the valid rows and then set their values. This seems overkill for your use case, though.

Comment: with your solution the script runs just as I require. Thanks very much.